# CSS selectors not applying correctly

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm seeing an odd outcome in some CSS/HTML code that I've written.  I have two different classes in my CSS; let's call them classA and classB.  Class A defines tables to have no borders:

```
div.classA table, th, td { borders:none }
```

Class B defines tables to have collapsed grey borders:

```
div.classB table, th, td  { border:1px solid grey }
```

My HTML then has

```
<div class="classB">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Text</th><th>More text</th>
     </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

The table heads (which, as classB should have borders) appear with no borders.  When I use Firefox to inspect the page, it shows me that classA has overridden the settings of classB, even though the table is within a classA div element.

What am I missing?

Comment: I assume `borders` in the first example is a typo? (`border`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selectors are not quite right. I think you want this:

```
div.classA table, div.classA th, div.classA td { border: 0; }

div.classB table, div.classB th, div.classB td  { border: 1px solid grey; }
```

(You need the div.classname before each tag.)

Comment: Thank you.  This solved the problem.  This is what I get for copying CSS code from online tutorials without fully understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

In your table's `thead` there's no `td`, instead it's `th` and to apply style only to the `th` you can use

```
div.classA table thead th { border:none }
div.classB table thead th { border:1px solid grey }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/elomen/7/edit).

**Update:** For Border in the full table (classB) you may try this

```
div.classB table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
div.classB table th, div.classB table td { 
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/elomen/5/edit).

Comment: This will neither omit nor include the border from the table itself, or the TBODY cells.

Comment: @KevinBoucher, He is talking about `thead` in his question he mentioned `The table heads (which, as classB should have borders) appear with no borders.`

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues to address:

## 1

You're not using the HTML tags correctly:

```
<div class="classB">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Text</th><th>More text</th>
     </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Should be:

```
<div class="classB">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Text</th><th>More text</th></tr>
     </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

## 2

Your mistyped "border" with "borders":

```
    div.classA table, th, td { borders:none }
```

Should be:

```
    div.classA table, th, td { border:none }
```

---

## 3

Borders are set to the `td` element, and by your classes, both target that element independently, because you're using a coma to split the declaration.
Additionally, the scope needs to be adjusted:

```
    div.classA table, th, td { border:none }
    div.classB table, th, td { border:1px solid grey }
```

Should be:

```
    div.classA table th, div.classA table td { border:none }
    div.classB table th, div.classB table td { border:1px solid grey }
```

---

### To have it all working properly, you should use:

See this [working fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/TbnYE/)!

**HTML**

```
<div class="classA">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Text</th><th>More text</th></tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="classB">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Text</th><th>More text</th></tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.classA table th, div.classA table td { border:none }
div.classB table th, div.classB table td { border:1px solid grey }
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections.  The actual HTML source I'm working with is several hundred lines long and I obviously didn't want to post the whole thing.  Sorry about the mistakes in my excerpt.